# inserting spaces inbetween only capital letters that are directly adjacent to each other

Tags: regex, awk, text, sed

My goal is to add spaces in between letters of various abbreviations.

There are three conditions for abbreviations:

1. abbreviations contain at least two or more letters.
2. abbreviations are always capitalized.
3. special character "/" is considered a capitalized letter

think of DNS, IP, TCP/IP, etc.

I would like to do text processing on them to turn into:

`D N S`

`I P`

`T C P / I P`

etc.
Lets say I have this sentence

> Because IP provides this basic routing function, the term “IP router,” is often used. Other, older terms for router are (IP gateway), [Internet gateway], and 'gateway'. TCP/IP 12345.

Running this command kinda solves my problem: `sed -e "s/[a-z \, \. \' \“ \” \( \) 0-9]*/& /g" -e "s/  */ /g" test.txt`
It doesn't get it quite perfectly.

I get this:

> Because I P provides this basic routing function, the term “ I P router,” is often used. Other, older terms for router are ( I P gateway), [ Internet gateway ], and 'gateway'. T C P / I P 12345.

There is still a space between " and I P .

There is a space between ( and I P .

There is also a space between [ and Internet.

escaping [ and ] with `$ sed -e "s/[a-z \, \. \' \“ \” \( \) \[ \] 0-9]*/& /g" -e "s/  */ /g" test.txt` doesn't work as shown below.

> Because IP provides this basic routing function, the term “IP router,” is often used. Other, older terms for router are (IP gateway), [Internet gateway], and 'gateway'. TCP/IP 12345.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the only special rule that would apply is that "/" is the only special character that should be treated like a capitalized letter. Other special characters do not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed and a conditional jump:

```
echo 'think of DNS, IP, TCP/IP, etc.' | sed -E ':x; s/([A-Z/])([A-Z/])/\1 \2/; tx'
```

Output:

```
think of D N S, I P, T C P / I P, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression

```
/([A-Z])([A-Z])/
```

Will match instances of two capital letters next to each other. You'd then want to use capturing groups in the replacement to get the same letters with a space between them.

```
/\1 \2/
```

This will only catch the first two capital letters in a row, so the output after the first iteration would look like:

```
Think of D NS, I P, T CP/I P, etc.
```

Therefore you need to repeat the substitution until the regex doesn't match. In Python this would be:

```
the_string = 'Think of DNS, IP, TCP/IP, etc.'

while re.search(r'([A-Z])([A-Z])', the_string):
    the_string = re.sub(r'([A-Z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', the_string)
```

`the_string` now ends up as:

```
Think of D NS, I P, T CP/I P, etc.
```